# Deterministically produce an array of indexes based on input number

Tags: collision-resistance, one-way-function

*Please see the Reference section below for terms.*

Is there a known one-way method to produce an array of indexes, based only on two input elements:

- length of the resulting array
- number, used as a key to deterministically produce the array

*If there exists only a method that can produce only fixed-length arrays - it can also be a good start for me.*

Examples:

| Length | Input number | Resulting array of indexes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 10001 | [3, 0, 2, 1] |
| 4 | 10002 | [2, 3, 1, 0] |
| 5 | 10001 | [2, 3, 4, 1, 0] |
| 5 | 10002 | [4, 3, 0, 1, 2] |

*Reference:*

- an **array of indexes**:
  Array, whose values are all integers from 0 to (array's length - 1), unordered.
- **deterministic** function:
  A function, producing the same result every time the same input data is provided

Answer (score 2):

Start with an array of sorted indices.

The [Durstenfeld Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) works by proceeding through the array, treating one part of the array as shuffled, and the rest of the array as un-shuffled. It simply swaps each of the items in the array with a random item from the un-shuffled region until the array is fully shuffled.

All permutations will be equiprobable.

A deterministic CSPRNG (seeded with your input number) is used to generate the random indices selected during the shuffle.

```
const csprng = new csprng(<input number seed>);
const len = 10;
const a = new Array(len);
for(let i=0; i<len; i++) a[i] = i;

for(let i=0; i<len; i++) {
  let swapIndex = nextDeterministicallyRandomIntBetween(i, len, csprng);
  let tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[swapIndex]; a[swapIndex] = tmp; // swap
}

function nextDeterministicallyRandomIntBetween(lowerBoundInclusive, 
    upperBoundExclusive, csprng) {

  return lowerBoundInclusive +
    nextDeterministicallyRandomIntLowerThan(upperBoundExclusive-lowerBoundInclusive, csprng);
}

function nextDeterministicallyRandomIntLowerThan(upperBoundExclusive, csprng) {
  // determine the minimum number of bits "b" required to represent
  // (upperBoundExclusive-1).  Then repeatedly ask the csprng for b bits
  // until it returns a result that is lower than upperBoundExclusive
  let b = Math.ceil(Math.log(upperBoundExclusive) / Math.log(2));
  let r;
  do {
    r = csprng.nextBits(b);
  } while (r>=upperBoundExclusive);
  return r;
}
```